# redirect_uri is not supported: facebook authentication for ionic and satellizer

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, satellizer

I am using the satellizer library for facebook authentication in my ionic app.

During development (which is done in the browser).. the satellizer fb object is configured as:

```
$authProvider.facebook({
  clientId: AppConstants.facebook.clientId,
  scope: 'user_friends',
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook'
});
```

This works fine. However the minute I run the app in the emulator I receive the following error:

```
The redirect_uri is not supported
```

How does one work around this ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you use the emulator (or phone) the default redirectUri becomes `file:///` which isn't allowed by Facebook. Change it to something like `http://localhost/` instead and add it also to allowed redirect uri in Facebook dev console.

Default config:
`redirectUri: window.location.origin + '/'`

Change to:
`redirectUri: 'http://localhost/'`

So your setup will look like:

```
$authProvider.facebook({
  clientId: AppConstants.facebook.clientId,
  scope: 'user_friends',
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook', 
  redirectUri: 'http://localhost/'
});
```